# ramdisk, compressed, writeable, no swap

Tags: filesystem, ram, compression

I need a ramdisk who handle transparent realtime compression on write and decompression on read.

Example : I use /dev/shm, or I create a new tmpfs, mount it writeable and compressed.

I wrote and read about 500 Mb - 1 GB of text files.
The files' content is not fixed, every few seconds the files are updated.

So squashfs / zramswap seems not to fit my goal.

I wonder about fusecompress or other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is possible to use zram without swap.

This script create a ram disk, maximum ram usage is 256 Mbyte.
You can run it with sudo or put the script in /etc/init.d/

```
#!/bin/bash

modprobe zram num_devices=1 
# max ram usage = 256 Mbytes
echo 256M > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mke2fs -q -m 0 -b 4096 -O sparse_super -L zram /dev/zram0
mount -o relatime,noexec,nosuid /dev/zram0 /mnt/zram
# eof
```

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/zram.txt

The value can be either in bytes or you can use mem suffixes. Example:
 echo 512M > /sys/block/zram0/disksize

Comment: What is the purpose of mentioned mount options?

Comment: `modprobe zram` just do nothing when `zram` module is already loaded.

Comment: As written might not free memory after files are deleted (on my system I encountered the issue), need to run `fstrim` to make memory available again. `discard` mount option might be doing same "automatically", now I'm testing it. Cheers and thanks.